# Route issue when paypal notify_url

Tags: codeigniter, paypal

I have call it in construction.

```
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();

    if( !$this->authentication->authenticate( $this->router->class ) ) {
        redirect('clients/');
    }

    $this->load->model('client_model', 'client');
    $this->layout = 'layout/web/client';
}
```

I am facing issue when paypal NOTIFY_URL hit the url its doesn't save credential and if i remove it from constructor it works.

```
function payment_notification()
{
    if( $this->input->post(NULL, TRUE) ) 
    {
        $this->saveintodb( $this->input->post() );          
    } else {
        show_error('Post data not found in request', 500);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not enough information supplied here...!

- Make sure the proper notify_url was sent to paypal
- Codeigniter wont allow the action if CSRF is enabled !
- You should check the the $_POST array rather than $this->input->post()

**Config.php**

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Check to see if the request uri contains paypal
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/
if( stripos($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"],'/paypal') )
{
    $config['csrf_protection'] = FALSE;
}
```

-
**Routes.php**

```
$route['paypal/notify'] = 'paypal/recieve_notification'; // www.mysite.com/paypal/notify
```

-
**Controllers/Paypal.php**

```
class Paypal extends CI_Controller{

    public function __construct(){ parent::__construct(); }

    public function recieve_notification() //simplified function
    {
        try(
            if( !$_POST )
                throw new Exception('No POST data recieved from Paypal');

            if( $_POST['verified'] !== 'VERIFIED') //im guessing here
                throw new Exception('User not verified by paypal');


        )catch(Exception $e){
            //debugging: show_error($e->getMessage());
            log_message('error', $e->getMessage());
            redirect('/');
            exit;
        }

            //Save to DB
            $this->saveintodb( $_POST ); //expecting Exception thrown from DB ?

        $this->session->flashdata('success', 'Data Saved!');
        redirect('/');
    }


}
```

Comment: Its not Paypal issue, its construction issue... its not even accessible by url. i mean http://localhost/site/client/function/ 

This redirect me to clients page because of constructor


`class Clients extends MY_Controller
{
 function __construct()
 {
  parent::__construct();
  
  if( !$this->authentication->authenticate( $this->router->class ) ) {
   redirect('clients/');
  }

  $this->load->model('client_model', 'client');
  $this->layout = 'layout/web/client';
 }
}`